# SQL statement to dax

Tags: sql-server, dax

How to transform my SQL statement to dax?

I have written this SQL statement:

```
Select * 
from my_table 
where color_column in ('red', 'green', 'white')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should return the entire table filtered as desired:

```
NewTable = 
   FILTER(my_table, my_table[color_column] IN {"red", "green", "white"})
```

Comment: I Have some problems here, when i trying to import table from cube using  your dax query statement it is not working.

Comment: DataSource.Error: AnalysisServices: Query (1, 25) The syntax for '[color_column]' is incorrect. (new table = FILTER(mytable, mytable[color_column] IN {"red", "green", "white})).

Comment: Hm this works if `my_table` exists within the report file or dataset. I don't know how and what you are querying. Maybe, following samples [from this site](https://www.sqlshack.com/query-ssas-tabular-model-database-using-dax-functions/) you could try `EVALUATE(FILTER('my_table', [color_column] IN {"red", "green", "white"}))` (see 4. Filter function)